# Android adding event to a CustomPreference element (TextView)

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, preferences

I'm doing an with a PreferenceActivity with two Fragments, each one containing a PreferenceScreen.

The thing I want to do is to create an event listener on a Custom preference that I have (a row of this custom Preference is a TextView with a SwitchView). I handle well the Switch preference, it keeps it saved as I want, but now what I want to do is add an event on the TextView between the SwitchView to show what I want on the other part of the screen (the second Fragment).

Let me show you my current code.
This is my CustomPreference (it's just a TextView and a Switch)

```
public class ItemPreference extends Preference{

private static TextView text;   // this is the text at the left of the switch, it's where i want to handle the event 
                                // to show an other preferencescreen in the fragment between
private Switch switcher;        // the key of the preference is for the SWITCH !!
private boolean checked;
private Context context;

public TextView getCustomText(){
    return text;
}

public ItemPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.context = context;     
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.row_setting);  // the layout resource of my custom preference
}


@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonRowSetting);

    // to display the text in the TextView between the Switch, I use the key of the Switch
    if (this.getKey().equals("pref_key_classification"))        
        text.setText(R.string.title_activity_classification);

    // the switchview and it's preference saving
    switcher = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.switchRowSetting);
    Boolean value = this.getPersistedBoolean(false);
    if (value){
        switcher.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        switcher.setChecked(false);
    }

    switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            setSwitchChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });
}

public void setSwitchChecked(boolean value) {
    if (checked != value) {
        checked = value;
        persistBoolean(value);
        notifyDependencyChange(shouldDisableDependents());
        notifyChanged();
    }
}

@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    return a.getBoolean(index, false);
}

@Override
protected void onClick() {
    super.onClick();
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
    setSwitchChecked(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedBoolean(checked) : (Boolean) defaultValue);
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    return super.onSaveInstanceState();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}   
}
```

This is the SettingsFragment, on the left part of the screen, where I want to handle the event to show what I want on the other part of the screen.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);     // the left preferencefragment 

    Preference stat = (Preference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_statistic));
    stat.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                 public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {                       
                     if(getActivity() instanceof OnSettingPageListener){
                      // if i click on this preference, this loads this preferencescreen on the other fragment, works well.
                        ((OnSettingPageListener)getActivity()).onSettingPageChange(R.xml.settings_stat);
                     }
                     return true;
                 }
             });

    // this is the custompreference, i would like to handle here a listener on the TextView to display a specific preferencescreen on the other fragment
    ItemPreference classif = (ItemPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_classification));  

    // i tried this, and i also tried to make my own Listener also, but doesn't works
    classif.getCustomText().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getActivity() instanceof OnSettingPageListener){
            // the content i want to load on the other fragment
                ((OnSettingPageListener)getActivity()).onSettingPageChange(R.xml.settings_classification);
            }               
        }
    });
}

// [...]
}
```

So I hope you understand what's my problem, it's just a matter of listener. Does someone has a solution?

Comment: no, didnt get it. what you want to actually do ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want the event on your first fragment to *show* the second fragment (for further editing) or if you want the event to make a change *visible* to the second fragment.

Let's say you want the change to be visible to the second fragment:

- Have your second fragment implement `SharedPreference.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` with method `onSharedPreferenceChanged`, implemented to do what you want to have happen when the preference in the first fragment changes.
- In the second fragment's `onResume` method, call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` on your SharedPreferences object.
- In the second fragment's `onPause` method, call `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` on your SharedPreferences object.

Now, if you want to show the second fragment for editing the preference in the first fragment:

- Give your preference a `fragment` attribute that declares the fragment class that edits your preference
- Have your first fragment implement `PreferenceFragment.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback` with method `onPreferenceStartFragment` implemented to instantiate your second fragment and display it.  Your `PreferenceActivity` subclass will invoke this callback when the preference is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, my problem was the way the handle a listener on the textview of my custom preference. I followed the observer pattern and made it work on my own listener.

On my fragment I instantiated my CustomSwitchPreference (I just renamed the ItemPreference class you can see upstairs ^^). I called my own listener, you will see the code after.

```
CustomSwitchPreference classif = (CustomSwitchPreference) 
                findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_classification));

classif.setHandlerListener(new ItemPreferenceTextViewListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onHandle(TextView textView) {
            if (getActivity() instanceof OnSettingPageListener){
                ((OnSettingPageListener)getActivity())
                        .onSettingPageChange(R.xml.settings_classification);
            }               
        }
    });
```

And there we go for the listener in the CustomPreference class, first create an interface to made your own listener (you can write it in the same file as the CustomPreference class you are doing) :

```
interface ItemPreferenceTextViewListener {
// the function which is going to be called when we will use our listener
    void onHandle(TextView textView);
}
```

And then in the CustomPreference class you do this :

```
// you can put the interface here if you want to make it visible

public class CustomSwitchPreference extends Preference {

private static TextView text;
// the key of the preference is for the SWITCH !! this activates or 
// not the "game" on the mainscreen
private Switch switcher; 
private boolean checked;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------- \\
// create a listener in your own custom preference

ItemPreferenceTextViewListener itemPreferenceTextViewListener ;

// this is the function to handle the event on the textview of the 
// custom preference item, creates the listener
public void setHandlerListener(ItemPreferenceTextViewListener listener) {
    itemPreferenceTextViewListener = listener;
}

// to make the event happen on a textview 
// (we will pass the right textview in the onBindView(....) )
protected void myEventListener(TextView textView)   {
    if(itemPreferenceTextViewListener!=null)
        itemPreferenceTextViewListener.onHandle(textView);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------- \\

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setLayoutResource(R.layout.row_setting);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    // the TextView at the right of the switch, this one 
    // handles a listener to show the other page preference
    text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonRowSetting); 
    // I called it buttonRowSetting because it will handle an event like a button

    // I set the text of this TextView with the 
    // key preference of the related switch
    if (this.getKey().equals("pref_key_classification"))        
        text.setText(R.string.title_activity_classification);
    else if (this.getKey().equals("pref_key_matching"))
        text.setText(R.string.title_activity_matching);
    else if (this.getKey().equals("pref_key_intruder"))
        text.setText(R.string.title_activity_intruder);
    else if (this.getKey().equals("pref_key_semantic"))
        text.setText(R.string.title_activity_semantic);

    // AND HERE it's where it happens, simply make a basic listener 
    // on the textview, and inside the onClick method, handle your own 
    // listener, on the TextView you initialized just before)
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            // just call 
            itemPreferenceTextViewListener.onHandle(text);
        }
    });

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------- \\
    // to keep the Switch saved in the preferences 
    switcher = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.switchRowSetting);        
    Boolean value = this.getPersistedBoolean(false);
    if (value){
        switcher.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        switcher.setChecked(false);
    }

    switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            setSwitchChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------- \\
}


public void setSwitchChecked(boolean value) {
    if (checked != value) {
        checked = value;
        persistBoolean(value);
        notifyDependencyChange(shouldDisableDependents());
        notifyChanged();
    }
}

@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    return a.getBoolean(index, false);
}

@Override
protected void onClick() {
    super.onClick();
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, 
                                 Object defaultValue) {
    setSwitchChecked(restorePersistedValue 
        ? getPersistedBoolean(checked) : (Boolean) defaultValue);
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    return super.onSaveInstanceState();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
}
```

Hope this helps, it was my mistake I did not called the onHandle method inside the myTextView.onClickListener. Hope this will help one to understand well how the observer pattern works.